# AzerothCore: set creature MovementType 1 does not make it random move

Tags: azerothcore

Yesterday I compiled AzerothCore, by following the step by step guide. I have a working server so decided to make some small edits, just to test.

I am using https://github.com/BAndysc/WoWDatabaseEditor/blob/master/README.md to edit the database.

I'm trying to make Argent Commander have random movement with the code below this post, but somehow they do not start moving. Any guess where i'm wrong at?
Note: Argent Commander should not have random movement, just doing this as a test.

`` UPDATE `creature_template` SET `MovementType` = 1 WHERE `entry` = 37965; ``

Answer (score 1):

you have to also set `wander_distance` for the npc in `creature` table

https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/creature#wander_distance

Sadly you can't do that yet in the wow db editor editor

Comment: you can do it in Keira3